# Delegate selected options only?

Tags: javascript

The update function should accept an options object.

Properties on the object passed to the Intercom function should only be set when options object sent to update had corresponding properties.

How can I do this?

```
function update(options) {
    Intercom('update', {
        email: options.email || noProperty,
        user_id: options.userId || noProperty,
    });
}
```

Comment: You code appears to already be doing this. E.g. Email will only be set to options.email if options.email is set, otherwise it will take the value of noProperty.

Comment: I would suggest to use utility library such as Underscore - it has appropriate method allowing to fallback to default values. Otherwise you have to write your own one using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try preparing the object to update before calling the function:

```
function update(options) {
    var toUpdate = {};
    if(options.email) {
       toUpdate.email = options.email;
    }
    if(options.userId) {
       toUpdate.user_id = options.userId;
    }
    Intercom('update', toUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use options.hasOwnProperty(prop)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

The hasOwnProperty function will return true if the property exists and false otherwise.